# Nokia E71 to Sonicwall GroupVPN

Tags: vpn, sonicwall

Does anyone know the settings I need to get a Nokia E71 to connect to a Sonicwall GroupVPN connection?

Comment: I've made some progress, it now connects and I can authenticate successfuly. But the SonicWall doesn't appear to be giving the Nokia an IP address (I've got the 'Use Internal Addressing' turned on in the Nokia VPN client)

I'm getting two error messages on the Sonic Wall:
WAN GroupVPN policy does not allow static IP for Virtual Adapter
and
IPSec proposal does not match (Phase 2) 

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The settings need to be whatever you made the settings on the Sonicwall.
Note that terminology can differ between vendors, so on the Nokia may be different to Sonic.

Each phase can have its own settings for authentication and encryption, and these are distinct on the Sonicwall, referred to IKE (Phase 1) and Ipsec (Phase 2) proposals. Both phases must match between your Sonic and client. If you only see one set of options on your client, then you may need both phases to use the same encryption.  I'm not familiar with the Nokia's VPN client options.

A "virtual adaptor" is a means of assigning a LAN IP address to a remote device. Under "Client" settings on the group VPN on Sonic, there are options for virtual adaptors to use DHCP and/or Manual Config; I expect this relates to your static IP issue. Either change the Sonic to allow DHCP + Manual, or change the Nokia to request an IP address by DHCP.